# How do i run a saved project from command line in CppCheck

Tags: jenkins, cppcheck

I created a project in CppCheck named `CppCheck_MainRls.cppcheck`
that includes several directories, i can run the project from the gui and it's working.
my project is huge so i only need a few directories to pass through CppCheck and export the result into xml file (later to be read by jenkins)

The current command line is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Cppcheck\CppCheck.exe" --enable=all  --xml-version=2 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\MainRls\workspace\Labs\VC++\AllShared" 2> cppcheck_result.xml
```

which is working great for the "AllShared" directory, how can i change it to read my project file?

Answer (score 5):

I am a cppcheck developer. Currently, you can't use a gui project file directly in the shell client. However it is a good idea to allow it.

Comment: Thank you, can you give any workaround how to check several directories from command line and export into one xml (to be read by jenkins) ?

Comment: I spent about an hour trying to get this to work (cppcheck v1.86), because surely it would, only to find this response on SO. Very disappointing and annoying.

Comment: Since time has changed, and thankfully you implemented this feature as described in [the answer given by Mike B.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61367105/2932052): I'm using version 2.9, so it should work, but it didn't. I tried `cppcheck --help` and also read [the docs mentioned there](https://cppcheck.sourceforge.io/manual.pdf). Is this feature maybe broken temporarily? Thanks in advance for taking a look!

Comment: It should work. Would it be possible to discuss your problems in cppcheck forum? https://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/discussion/ ?

Answer (score 4):

As of April 2020 (cppcheck v1.90), this is supported per the [cppcheck manual](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/manual.pdf) (PDF) section 3.1:

> 3.1 Cppcheck GUI project
>
> You can import and use Cppcheck GUI project files in the command line tool:
>
> `cppcheck --project=foobar.cppcheck`

Comment: In version 2.9, this is not working as described by the documentation. I'm getting *cppcheck: error: could not find or open any of the paths given.*, while it runs fine in the Cppcheck GUI application. Do you have any ideas what to try next?